# Pausing MQ Queue Manager using SIGSTOP

Tags: ibm-mq

I have simple IBM MQ application: there are 2 queues -> one receive queue and obviously another one is send queue. Now I put a large number messages into receive queue and while the application is processing the messages, I pause the MQ core process using SIGSTOP.

Should the message flow stop immediately? This is what is happening in my case:

The application can receive all the messages and push them to the send queue after processing. Now if I try push further messages into receive queue, the MQ putter (a sample utility program) cannot push the messages which is usual.

My question is: how should MQ behave in this case? Should the message flow not stop immediately after SIGSTOP signal? My application program does not catch any exception also.

Any answer would be helpful.

Comment: I can barely bring myself to +1 this but if just one other person reads it and doesn't do what is suggested, it'll be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that nobody can tell you how WMQ is supposed to behave in this situation because OMG, DON'T DO THAT!

Someone asked a similar question lately on the list server.  Andrew Hickson of the WMQ development team responded thus:

> Sending a STOP signal to an MQ server side application is dangerous
>   enough, but sending a STOP signal to an MQ process (e.g amqrmppa)
>   would be extremely dangerous. If that process happened to own an inter
>   process lock at the time the STOP signal arrived the entire queue
>   manager could easily grind to a halt. The same issue does arise for a
>   'simple' server side application (for example queue manager scope
>   locks are obtained/released during MQCONN processing), but the scope
>   for inadvertently stopping the queue manager is much greater with an
>   MQ internal process.

The obvious question here is what do you consider to be "the MQ core process"?  The controller?  One of the agent processes?  They are all intercommunicating and there is no single process that represents "the QMgr."

If you need to interrupt processing, use the WMQ facilities such as disabling PUT or GET on the queue, terminating the connection to the QMgr, etc.

Comment: I don't really want to do this. But my client is doing and bugging for explanation. By MQ Core process, I mean amqzxma0 (from ps -ef).

Comment: The answer for your client is that IBM does not recommend or support issuing SIGSTOP against individual QMgr processes and the results are undefined.  The good news is that WMQ is extremely robust and built to preserve data integrity in such situations, but that doesn't mean that it's impossible to shoot yourself in the foot this way. Use only the documented APIs and commands except as directed by Support.

Comment: I agree with T.Rob... this is a stupid thing to do...amqzxma0 is the execution controller - its pretty much a coordinator for what else goes on - for example, any new process connecting to the qmgr needs to use it to allocate an agent process. Its the EC which periodically checks the health of other processes, or cleans up some dead processes - pause it and you are **asking** asking for trouble. DONT DO IT...

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Just one more question. Can anybody please provide the link to the page where IBM does not recommend or support issuing SIGSTOP against queue manager processes? Sadly, I cannot find it.

Comment: There isn't one.  There are an infinite number of bad things one might do to the QMgr and they don't document all of them.  They document what you *are* supposed to do and assume if it isn't documented you won't try to do it.

Comment: When many people hurt themselves doing the same thing, IBM will issue a Technote or update the docs.  This is the first time I've heard of anyone trying to do this.  If you wish to see this documented, try to get hundreds of other customers to claim this as necessary function and have them open PMRs against it.  Once IBM realizes they need a warning label saying "DON'T RANDOMLY ISSUE SIGSTOP AGAINST QMGR PROCESSES, THE SURGEON GENERAL HAS DETERMINED THIS IS DETRIMENTAL TO THE HEALTH OF THE QMGR AND INTEGRITY OF YOUR DATA" then they will issue a Technote or update the Infocenter.